# ZODB does not release hard-disk space

Tags: python, python-3.x, zope, zodb

I tested ZODB by creating a huge object, committed, then it gave a warning. 
Next, I proceeded to delete the object from root, commit. The .fs file was still 1GB in space. I then killed the REPL. I reopened python, made the connection, but now I cannot seem to get rid of this 1 GB file (other than trying to delete it from the disk itself).

Code something like:

```
storage = FileStorage('Data.fs')
db = DB(storage)
connection = db.open()
root = connection.root()
```

Followed by creating some huge object and at first I actually did

```
root['bigObj'] = 'small_str',
transaction.commit()
```

to try and overwrite. After which I just deleted the key/value.

What part am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

ZODB is append-only database. ZODB never reclaims or overwrites old information unless explicitly told to do so. This means that you have infinite undo history to the point the database was created if needed.

To reclaim the disk space you need to [pack ZODB database](http://docs.plone.org/develop/plone/persistency/database.html#packing-database).

Other databases (MySQL, PostgreSQL) have similar characteristics. For example, PostgreSQL must be `VACUUM`ed time to time.

Comment: Btw, I'm maintaining a list that I share among threads. It's really simple with ZODB, but this list changes a lot. Considering this append-only situation, do you perhaps some advice for that (probably that it is not a good idea)?

Comment: ZODB should not be problem for most of use cases - if you are using native ZODB lists then it should write only the delta to the database on each update (though I need to confirm that). Please see http://zodborg.readthedocs.org/en/latest/documentation/guide/modules.html#persistent-list-persistentlist - use PersistentList instead of []. This is how ZODB works - you really can't change the nature of the beast. If you need to deal with large, mutable, blobs I suggest you consider alternative databases. Here is one approach for ZODB like behavior on PostgreSQL https://github.com/Shoobx/pjpersist

Comment: @PascalvKooten: there are ZODB backends that can be configured to discard historical revisions; `RelStorage` can do this. The default `FileStorage` backend however cannot.